# A winform with the same usercontrol called twice. Error : The INSERT Statement Conflicted With the FOREIGN KEY Constraint

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress

I have a winform with the same usercontrol called twice of which one shows a previous record and the other is used for new record entry. When saving the new record i get "The INSERT Statement Conflicted With the FOREIGN KEY Constraint". How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Without any code, no we can't help you

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please write a summarized title and put the rest of the explanation in the body

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
When passing values to bound controls, the datatype should match. i.e,
I was passing numeric value as text to a decimal field in DB which was triggering "The INSERT Statement Conflicted With the FOREIGN KEY Constraint", even though it was not a foreign key constraint.

This gave the error:
Me.Xfrm_ctl_sales_QTN2.REQ_QTN_KIT_LINEAR_MTRTextEdit.text=Me.Xfrm_ctl_sales_QTN1.REQ_QTN_KIT_LINEAR_MTRTextEdit.text

This fixed the error:
Me.Xfrm_ctl_sales_QTN2.REQ_QTN_KIT_LINEAR_MTRTextEdit.EditValue =Me.Xfrm_ctl_sales_QTN1.REQ_QTN_KIT_LINEAR_MTRTextEdit.EditValue